# How to catch error?

Tags: angularjs

I have a textbox for searching pin:

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="pin">
    <input type="submit" value=""SEARCH" class="btn btn-search" ng-click="ShowDetailsAboutPin(pin);">
```

My function:

```
 $scope.ShowDetailsAboutPin = function (pin) {
        if ($scope.showdetail == false && pinTicket != null) {
            $scope.showdetail = true;
            $scope.pin = pin;

            $("#background").addClass("darker");

            $http.get(PinUrl+ 'Pin/'+ $scope.pin)
           .then(Details, ErrorResponse);

        }
        else {
            $scope.showdetail = false;
            $("#background").removeClass("darker");
        }
    }



     var Details = function (response) {
            $scope.data = response.data;
            $scope.Detail = $scope.data;
        }
```

Everything works fine when user enter valid pin but i want to "catch" error when user enter non valid pin. I get message in console of browser

> not found

but how can i catch that 404 not found message?

Comment: What kind of error you wanna catch? A server error? A 404 Not Found form the server? A valid server response with a validation error message? An error in the JavaScript code? You need to be more specific about your question and provide a plunker if possible

Comment: 404 Not Found because that error i get when i enter non valid pin

Comment: As a side note when you use `ng-model` the variable is automatically wired in your controller `$scope`, e.g. you don't need to pass it as a variable and assign it to the scope (`$scope.pin = pin;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation for angular [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Using the .success and .error methods will give you all the information you need.

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If pin should consist of only integers , why don't you use regex, it can be done in the views only, suppose it is a five-digit, then in the input use.

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/\b\d{5}\b/g" class="form-control" ng-model="pin">
```

or in your code,  you can make the api call only with valid pins by,

```
   var pinRegex = /\b\d{5}\b/g;

   if (pinRegex.test) {
      $http.get(PinUrl+ 'Pin/'+ $scope.pin)
          .then(Details, ErrorResponse);
  }
```

Comment: i have api..and im doing api call to check if pin is valid or not